# Ideal power supply for ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

What is the ideal power supply for this module? What do you use that works ok?

Will the [AMS1117](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5PCS-5V-to-3-3V-DC-DC-Step-Down-Power-Supply-Buck-Module-AMS1117-LDO-800MA-CM10-/321963058956?hash=item4af67e670c:g:6hcAAOSwo3pWfi4t) work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work. However, ignore the entire description.

That is **NOT** a buck regulator - it is a low-dropout **linear** regulator.  Thus it will waste power as heat - the more current you draw the hotter it will get.

The '1117' range of regulators are pretty much ubiquitous. I use them in a wide range of products and situations where power consumption isn't critical (i.e., not battery based products).

For lower power requirements you want to get a *real* buck regulator. Something more like this: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/301842020065

**Note that it's an adjustable module, and you will need to first use a multimeter to adjust the output to 3.3V before you connect it up.**

Because they are adjustable they are a great thing to keep around since you can use them for all sorts of different situations.

Comment: This looks better. Will the element i ordered require additional capacitors? I'll order a couple of these too.

Comment: No, the 1117 board has the capacitors on it already.

Comment: My bad. I should have read better.